# Show that the vector field does not have periodic orbit

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Show that the vector field $F(x,y)=(2x-x^5-xy^4,y-y^3-x^2y)$ defined in $R^2$ does not have periodic orbits; the Bendixson criterion is not useful.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! Please consider adding more context and your efforts so far. A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For typesetting, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 6):

Since the $x$ and $y$ axes are invariant, any periodic orbit must be in one of the four quadrants.  A periodic orbit must have a stationary point in its interior, but every stationary point is on an axis.

Answer (score 0):

@Robert Israel provides the best answer. This post is an elaboration of his remarks.

## Dynamical System

Find the periodic solution for the dynamical system:
$$
%
\begin{align}
%
 \dot{x} &= -x \left(x^4+y-2\right) \\
%
 \dot{y} &= -y \left(x^2+y^2-1\right) \\
%
\end{align}
\tag{1}
%
$$

### Poincaré–Bendixson Theorem

Use the theorem of Poincare and Bendixson to identify a *trapping region*, an area where the sign of the radial time derivative can change.

The trapping region must

1. Be closed and bounded,
2. Not contain any critical points.

### Fixed points

Proceed by locating fixed points.

#### Nullclines

Find the nullclines.
$$
\begin{array}{ccccl}
  \dot{x} = 0 &\implies &y &= &\left\{ 2-x^4 \right\} \\
  \dot{y} = 0 &\implies &x &= &\left\{ 0, \pm\sqrt{1-x^2} \right\}
\end{array}
$$

#### Identify fixed points

The fixed points are:
$$
\left[ \begin{array}{c}
 \dot{x} \\ \dot{y}
\end{array} \right]_{(0,0)}
=
\left[ \begin{array}{c}
 \pm\sqrt[4]{2} \\ 0
\end{array} \right]
$$

At this juncture, invoke the arguments of @Robert Israel and you are done.

To reinforce the lesson, the answer continues with the canonical approach. The plot below shows the flow and the $\dot{x}$ nullcline in black and the $\dot{y}$ nullcline in red.

[image: flow]

### Compute $\dot{r}$

The polar coordinate transform
$$
%
\begin{align}
%
 x &= r \cos \theta \\
%
 y &= r \sin \theta \\
%
\tag{2}
\end{align}
%
$$

implies
$$
  r^{2} = x^{2} + y^{2}
\tag{3}
$$

Differentiate (3) with respect to time:
$$
2r\dot{r} = 2x \dot{x} + 2y \dot{y}
$$
Therefore
$$
\dot{r} = \frac{x \dot{x} + y \dot{y}} {r}
\tag{4}
$$
Transform $\dot{x}$ and $\dot{y}$ to $r$ and $\theta$ using (2):
$$
%
\begin{align}
%
 \dot{x} 
&= -x \left(x^4+y-2\right) 
= -r \cos \theta \left(r^4 \cos ^4\theta+r \sin \theta-2\right) \\
%
 \dot{y} 
&= -y \left(x^2+y^2-1\right)
= -r \left(r^2-1\right) \sin \theta \\
%
\end{align}
%
$$
Inserting these identities in $(4)$ produces the final differential equation:
$$
\dot{r} = -r \left(-\sin ^2\theta+r^4 \cos ^6\theta+r^2 \sin ^4\theta+\cos ^2\theta (r \sin \theta-1) (r \sin \theta+2)\right)
\tag{5}
$$

The fact that this differential equation is so difficult is a sign that you have either made a mistake, or missed the reasoning on stationary points.

To close the discussion, examine the plot below which shows $\dot{r}\left(r, \theta\right)$. The purple line is the nullcline $\dot{r}=0$. Below the line $\dot{r}>0$, above the line $\dot{r}<0$.

[image: rdot]